# Iteration through Hierarchical Data in SQL

Tags: sql, while-loop, hierarchical-data

After reading several related articles, I've written a CTE query to iterate through my hierarchical data. Here's the scenario:

In a security table, there are Menu IDs, Titles, Parent Menu IDs, and Invisibility. I've written the logic to loop through and show the path for a specific child menu. Since this is a query designed to only show menu items a specific user has access to, I need to be able to eliminate any menu item and it's child menus where the Invisibility field is set to true. Here's an example for those who understand better with visuals.

```
 MenuID       Title            ParentMenuID    Invisibility
 MAIN         Main Menu                         0
 LEVEL1       Management       MAIN             1
 LEVEL2       Operation MGMT   LEVEL1           0
```

In the provided scenario, only the Main Menu would be returned by the query since the user doesn't have access to anything beneath it. Even though LEVEL2 is technically visible to the user, it's parent menu is inaccessible, so it inherits that value.

What I'd like is to be able to write logic against my CTE query to say "only return the values from the query until the invisibility is 1, then ignore all other values." However, I'm stumped on how to do this. I know it's possible to write WHILE loops, but I'm not familiar with them. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Does adding `where child.Invisibility=0` in the recursive part of your `cte` not provide the desired output?

Comment: @SqlZim the Invisibility field is defined within the select statement of the cte. It's not a native field to the database table.

Comment: Post your code?

Comment: sql and while-loop tags don't make sense together.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple recursive CTE.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT MenuID, Title, 1 as Level
   FROM TABLE_NAME_YOU_DIDNT_SAY
   WHERE ParentMenuID is null and Invisiblity = 0

   UNION ALL

   SELECT X.MenuID, X.Title, CTE.Level+1 as Level
   FROM CTE
   JOIN TABLE_NAME_YOU_DIDNT_SAY AS X ON X.ParentMenuID = CTE.MENUID AND X.Invisiblitiy = 0 
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Level ASC
```

> *please never use the word "loop" or "while-loop" near SQL again.  :)*
>
> *SQL is for set based operations not iterative ones.*

Comment: Invisibility isn't a native field to the table; it was created via a CASE statement. I created a view of my original CTE query to pull information from so that the Invisibility field is linked to the query.    The issue is that this doesn't resolve the problem. If a child's parent has an Invisibility of 1, but the child has an Invisibility of 0, the child is still pulling through using the query you provided.

Comment: @user2572833 -- no that is not how recursive CTEs work -- this code will only pull "MAIN" in the example data given.

Comment: I'm still a relatively new SQL writer, so I have almost no working knowledge of CTEs. All I know is that when I replicated the code you provided, thank you by the way, the LEVEL2 information still pulls through.  Is there any way I can filter the Invisible fields through some means other than another CTE query?

Comment: @user2572833 -  You must have made a typo in your query or your data is not as shown. **The only way I can help is if you show me the query you ran**